# Cannot properly overlay eigen_conversions

Tags: rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on Groovy and I would like to overlay the package `eigen_conversions`[1]. If I do `roscd eigen_conversions`, I land in the correct directory: `~/gggroovy/geometry/eigen_conversions`, my overlay. This indicates that my `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable is correct, as far as I know. My `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` indeed includes the path corresponding to my overlay, in addition to including at the end `:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks`

However, when I do `roscd eigen_conversions; rosmake`, I see

```
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions
```

But there is no `ROS_NOBUILD` inside `~/gggroovy/geometry/eigen_conversions`.

More importantly, when I try to build packages that depend on `eigen_conversions`, I get errors like

```
/opt/ros/groovy/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_kdl.h:66:6: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘void tf::vectorEigenToKDL(const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>&, KDL::Twist&)’
```

which indicate that the compiler is using the wrong include file, not the one in the overlay.

I have otherwise successfully done overlays.

[1 ]https://github.com/goretkin/geometry/tree/groovy-devel?files=1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210546/cannot-properly-overlay-eigen_conversions/) by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-04**:
Please add which version of `eigen_conversions` you are trying to build. Even the `groovy-devel` version seems like it is a catkin package, so I'm not sure `rosmake` should do anything with it.

**Comment by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on 2015-06-04**:
Ah, alright. I've included a link to the exact package I'd like to overlay, which is essentially groovy-devel.

Do you know what I can do to uncatkinize the package or make it otherwise be picked up by my system? I am using the PR2, and many packages I need are not catkinized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should create a catkin workspace which overlays any system catkin packages (such as eigen_conversions), and then set up your rosbuild workspace as an overlay on top of that.

Section 3.3 of [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin#rosbuild_workspace_on_top_of_catkin_workspace) does a decent job of describing the process in more detail.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1